# How to give symbol to the end of each row in html table

Tags: html

I have a html table

```
If Production Profit % between:
<table id="tableDataInp">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

How can I give a % sign at the end of each row? I tried using % sign after each  but %is displayed at the top of  table.

https://www.screencast.com/t/hZ9gebf1m Current Output

Expected Output : https://www.screencast.com/t/7OSfvlMgV5x  % should be displayed in place of Red Square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add an extra cell per row:

```html
<table id="tableDataInp">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td width="30">%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td width="30">%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have border in First Two Column and I don't want border on the last column which shows % sign How can I do this??

Comment: You can use CSS to remove the border from the last table cell, something like:  `#tableDataInp tr td:last-child { border:0; }`

Answer (score 4):

You could do it using CSS and an after element.

```css
table td:last-child::after {
  content: '%';
}
```

```html
<table id="tableDataInp">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So the CSS selector selects the last `td` in each row and adds an after element with the content of **%**

You can then apply further styling to the after element (margin, font size etc).

Answer (score 2):

Add `after pseudo` property

```
#tableDataInp tr:after{
  content:"%";
  color:#fff;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:red;
  padding:3px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/s25cvyda/2/

Comment: It worked but i had an one issue. I also have border in my Table which I didn't display on my question. By using this code % is displayed but with border. How can we remove border for only % sign